# Variable Creation Issues

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I'm creating a quick template in Netsuite using the freemarker engine (first time i've been exposed to it) and i'm struggling to find the correct syntax to perform the following.

I have the following 2 variables

item.rate & item.custcol_uom

I need to do the following

```
${formatAmount(item.rate/item.custcol_uom,"currency",".")}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freemarker offers several format directives for numbers including currency

```
${(item.rate/item.custcol_uom)?string.currency}
```

Check documentation here: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html

if for some reason you prefer to use method `formatAmount()` you should expose it to the freemarker engine

Another solution is to create a freemarker `macro`

```
<@macro format_amount rate uom >
    <#-- stuff here -->
</@macro>
```

Than call it

```
<@s.format_amount rate=item.rate uom=item.custcol_uom />
```

Macros in freemarker: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great, thanks alot! Think I will be sticking to the top way of doing it for now, but appreciate the extra detail.

Comment: is there a simple way to control the currency symbol applied?

Comment: If your formatting sticks with a given locale (currency, decimal & thousands formatting, dates, etc) use this: <#setting locale="en_US">

Comment: `format_amount` should certainly be a `#function`, not a `macro`. But, it's often better to register a custom number format, and then write something like `${item.rate?string.@amount}`; see http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html

Comment: @user1372212 The currency symbol is provided by the Java platform based on the current `locale` setting of FreeMarker (fustaki has shown a possible way of setting that, though generally it's better if you can set it outside the template). There's also the possibility of explicitly specifying it in the format pattern (see http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number), such as `'¤ ,##0;;currencyCode=USD'`. You probably want to specify such long winded things in the FreeMarker configuration as alias formats, and then you can write `${x?string.@usd}` etc.

Comment: @ddekany in the end the information given here lead me to use ?string["0.##"] and I then controlled the currency symbol with a standard IF from the 3 options i had available.

Comment: @user1372212 Note that you can write `<#setting number_format="0.##">` once (or the same set outside the templates), instead of writing `?string[...]`-s to multiple places.